# Effective Field Theory book club

Tags: discussion

I suspect this proposal is off-topic here but I thought I would give it a try. I apologize in advance if this is the case.

I've begun watching video lectures on Effective Field Theory with a focus on particle physics from [MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-851-effective-field-theory-spring-2013/index.htm) and going through the homework. I thought it would be fun to go through them at the same pace with other users on the site. That way we could ask questions the with regards to the lectures and the homework on Stackexchange and someone would likely be able to answer them. I think it would be good for the site and encourage high level questions.

My idea for the book club is to do 2 lectures a week and follow with the HW. I like to TeX notes for courses that I take so I'll provide lecture notes. If you would be interested in the idea let me know and I will put together a more firm proposal.

Also if you are not interested in joining but have any input on how such an idea would work best on the site, please let me know.

**Edit:** There are 26 lectures in total. I propose we aim for 2 lectures a week except on weeks where we do the homework, starting next week (have the first 2 lectures watched by the 17th). I think its best to make Monday as the "meeting day" and aim to have the lectures and HW done for this day each week.

I've watched the first couple lectures and I saw that the first HW should be done after the 3rd lecture. Please let me know if you think the plan needs some modification or have any ideas!

I will post lecture notes on my [website](http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/%7Eajd268/Notes.html) under Effective Field Theory link. Dilaton has been kind enough to open a chatroom for us over [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13401/effective-field-theory). If you would like to follow along please post so we know you exist! The goal is to have the first two lectures watched by Monday, March 17th.

Comment: @JeffDror Good idea! I am interested in this.

Comment: @JeffDror can you please write me an email when this gets started, as my comments saying that I want to take part in this book club too disappear for some reason?

Comment: @Dilaton: No problem. I'm good to start now. I was for an extra couple people, but 3 will need to due. I'm not sure how to create a chat room. Could you set that up? I will update the question to be more about the proposal.

Comment: @JeffDror I hope [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13401/effective-field-theory) chat room will do. Starting next week by watching the first two videos would be fine with me, I really hope I can take part ...

Comment: I'm interested, will post in the chat.

Comment: Great idea.....

Answer (score 4):

I think in terms of making it work on the site, your best bet would be to set up a chat room for those following along to discuss etc informally. When questions come up that are conceptual in nature and are a good fit for the site, it would be good to put them in as questions and answer them on the main site. But for other questions, particularly ones about how to work through the homework assignments, those would probably best be handled informally in a chat room.